# "stripe.reporting.reportRuns.create" returning file related data...I need JSON data

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripes

"stripe.reporting.reportRuns.create" returning file related data...I need json data..now Iam taking the xlsx file( using get file api of stripe) and then Iam converting that file to json data using external npm module..

[
{
"category": "starting_balance",
"description": "Starting balance (2023-02-28)",
"net_amount": 33871.49,
"currency": "usd"
}
]

### My code

```
   let data = req.query; const reportRun = await stripe.reporting.reportRuns.create({ report_type: "balance.summary.1", parameters: { interval_start: data.startDate, interval_end: data.endDate, timezone: "America/Los_Angeles", columns: ["category", "description", "net_amount", "currency"], }, });
```

const url = reportRun.result.url;
const id = reportRun.result.id;
const fileLink = await stripe.fileLinks.create({ file: id, }); //Reset of the code is xlsx to JSON data

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: let data = req.query;
const reportRun = await stripe.reporting.reportRuns.create({
 report_type: "balance.summary.1",
 parameters: {
  interval_start: data.startDate,
  interval_end: data.endDate,
  timezone: "America/Los_Angeles",
  columns: ["category", "description", "net_amount", "currency"],
 },
});
const url = reportRun.result.url;
const id = reportRun.result.id;
const fileLink = await stripe.fileLinks.create({
 file: id,
});
//Reset of the code is xlsx to JSON data

Comment: do not post code in a comment!  nobody can read that.  Edit the question.

Comment: ok.. question edited

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a webhook to listen to the `reporting.report_run.succeeded` trigger so you know when the report is ready to read.

Further details can be found in the documentation and this section specifically explains the recommended pattern on how to programmatically get report data.

https://stripe.com/docs/reports/api#integration-pattern

Comment: This is not getting report data. It's just a file link. That I already get.
I downloaded the file and converted to JSON(using xlsx module). I need get json data not file.